# Is there a cross-platform "time units separation" standard?

Tags: windows, backup, date, timestamps, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I create backups with `date` I usually put the current date as part of a backup file in the format of:
*year-month-day-hour:minute:second* so I get a file like:

```
database-username_database-name---2019-10-10-01:41:11.sql
```

I have a problem that if I store the file in Windows 10 the three colons of `01:41:11` are being encoded to some code I don't know instead appearing naturally as in *nix systems.

A nice solution would probably be using a *semicolon* as in `%H;%M;%S` instead `%T` (which is equivalent to `%H:%M:%S`) as there is no problem using semicolons in Windows.

Is there a **standard** time units separation, instead of *colon*, which is commonly usable to separate the times in *nix-win files, without producing such cross-platform conflicts? I wonder how will you "tackle" it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant standard for date and time representation is ISO-8601. For times, [the standard representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) use either a colon, or no separator, between hours, minutes and seconds. So I would suggest skipping the separator entirely:

```
database-username_database-name---2019-10-10-014111.sql
```

For the sake of consistency it might make sense to remove the separator between the year, month and day too.

(The rules for file names on Windows are [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).)